# What is the correlation between dielectric plates and capacitance?

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, capacitance, dielectric

A project I'm working on requires a capacitor of 37000 uF and a voltage rating of at least 10kV, but every capacitor I find online can only meet one of these standards and is very expensive, so layering them in series and parallel to stack up to what I need will be even more expensive. I'm planning to build my own capacitor out of plexiglass and aluminum foil because I've heard that homemade capacitors usually have a high voltage rating. How can I plan out the area and number of dielectric plates I'll need to get my desired capacitance and voltage rating? Should I use different materials? Or do you know of a capacitor I could buy online with something like the parameters I'm looking for?

Thank you

Comment: There are formulas all over the internet. http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Plate-Capacitor-Calculator.phtml

Comment: What @EugeneSh. said, and be prepared to build something the size of a football field, or several football fields. There is a reason this stuff is big and expensive.

Comment: Charging a 37000uF cap to 10kV is rather dangerous. Are you aware of the dangers?

Comment: Is this for DC or AC?

Answer (score 4):

37000uF at 10kV will store 1.85MJ. That's a lot of energy. In elephant/football field units, that's a 500kg grand piano being dropped from a height of 377m. I would not want to stand under that, or within a block of your capacitor.

Trying to 'roll your own' capacitor is a non-starter, for anything above a Joule or so. The manufacturers have access to very thin dielectric films and very thin metalisation, and the equipment to handle them. Whatever you make will be an order of magnitude or two larger than anything you can buy. They have know-how as well for how to avoid corona around the edges of the electrodes that will eat your dielectric and cause rapid failure. Hint, commercial 2kV capacitors are effectively several connected in series internally, to eliminate corona. A single 10kV section is not going to last long.

You need to buy multiple smaller capacitors, and connect them in series/parallel. Don't forget equalising resistors across each series bank, so that unequal capacitor leakage can't over-volt any of the banks. It will be worth setting up a spreadsheet for cost per stored joule versus capacity and voltage to get the most efficient bulk storage. You'll be able to take advantage of large quantity price breaks as well.

Comment: Just as a note, the energy is about the same as two sticks of dynamite!

Answer (score 2):

Using an online calculator and 1 mm thick plexiglas at 17 to 30 kV/mm dielectric strength and dielectric constant = 3, I calculated that an 11 meter cube of plexiglas would do the job. That is 11,000 squares of plexiglas each 11 meters square.

Answer (score 1):

What is the practical application of this project?

37mF (@ 50 Hz I assume) is around 100mΩ.  In order to be low loss, dissipation factor needs to be <<5% pref. 1% or 1mΩ which implies large surface area conductors.  Usually Litz Wire for RF or Flat straps for reasonably low inductance for line f that look like they are rated for >1kA.

Is this for DC or AC?  with a typical rating of 1kV/mm for air on sharp edges or 3kV/mm on flat surfaces and a dielectric constant of 4 to 5, PU (plexiglass} plastic is around 10kV/mm if clean and transformer oil is around 25kV/mm unless purified even further and conductors are dust/contaminant free.

Thus to make this an old fashioned oil-filled PFC tank with 1mm gap with diamond coated paper dilectric with Nynas oil filled in clean environment.  You can compute the RC values of 2mm sheet rolled copper with 1mm gap to determine surface area required from online calculators.  It would be a very large tank but easy for any gigawatt transformer factory to make.

For practical purposes 75kV/mm dielectric is needed which gets expensive with 99.999% mica and copper.  Perhaps, Tesla could afford it at one time and built one.

However I might assume you don't know what you are asking for , and if so, this will become an irrelevant answer.

A practical challenge is to use CRGOS (transformer steel with silicate coating) 0.3mm with 1%  coating and make it contaminant and burr free with about 10uF per layer 1m^2 (est) an ~400 layers clamped tight and edgs clean without burrs or magnetic silicate dust that will cause PD failures then corona. Possible yet impractical.

> A practical solution is a motor/generator operating with mechanical phase lead generation.  1/2CV^2= 74kW @ 50Hz with suitable margin and transformer to match voltage.  ~ 100kW diesel motor powered generator with phase lead control.

Comment: "A practical solution is a motor/generator operating with mechanical phase lead generation. " Can I get that in an SMT package.. It worked in LTSPICE....

Comment: certainly Super Mega Transformer dielectric

Comment: I suspect the purpose would only be for a rail gun of some kind. But a lot more powerful that most hobbyists could afford to build. But the voltage is about right for that amount of energy, depending on the inductances and resistances involved of course. (See DOI:10.1119/1.4760659, for example.)

Comment: You can store a lot more energy density with batteries than a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the hell you are trying to create but...
I don't think you can build that your self. Home made capacitors have only little capacitance. Capacitors with "High" capacitance and high voltage are used for example in Tesla generators (You know the halos that make beautiful sparks.) Even they do not go much past a few nF. http://www.hvtesla.com/mmc.html shows trays which give 25nF at 36KV. In your case you could build it into about 75nF at 12Kv and you would need about half a million of those trays. 
I suspect your calculations which come up to those requirement are wrong somehow. That thing would be able to store 3.7Mega watts of energy

Comment: +1 Me thinks someone spiced together a circuit and now wants to buy the part values he picked.

Comment: -1 Megawatts is a unit of power not energy. The requirement stated in the question would store 1.85 mega joules of energy.

Comment: And 'KV' is kelvin-volt. 'Kv' is meaningless and 'kV' is correct. Capitals matter.

Comment: @CharlesCowie true that.. ( or MW.s ) but either way, not something to be trifled with.